# Comparing regression coefficients of models with differnet dependent variables

Tags: regression

I am interested in comparing response (dependent) variables (2+) in a regression format where the models share the same data and design matrix.  As an example, lets say I am interested in whether numerical counts of aquatic organisms, or the biomass of those organisms is more "sensitive" to the same disturbance gradient (e.x., flood frequency).  So I figured, comparing regression coefficients, specifically slopes would be appropriate.

Could you please tell me if you have a better idea, or if this is not appropriate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slope is determined by the amount of relationship and the standard deviation of the variables.  Change from measuring mass in grams to measuring mass in kilograms and the slope will change.  So comparing estimated slopes directly could end up meaningless, being driven more by the scale of the variables than the degree of the relationship.

You could compare standardized slopes, or just look at correlation coefficients.